# Update props used in array of components being passed to other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using aui-react which have component named "AUIDialog".

This component requires to pass footer items as array of nodes, for example:

```
render() {
    let footerButtons = [
      <AUIButton>Example button</AUIButton>,
    ];

    return (
        <div>
            <AUIDialog footerActionContent={footerButtons}>
```

The trick is, if I use prop (or state, does not matter):

```
let footerButtons = [<AUIButton disabled={this.props.disabled}>Example button</AUIButton>];
```

Then this component is not re-rendered - it `disabled` is always same.

Is there any way to handle prop/state change in this component?

Comment: why can't you use `AUIButton ` inside `AUIDialog ` ?

Comment: I can, but I want to render it in a footer, not in dialog content

Comment: It looks like nodes passed as array are not re-rendered at all. I've tries to wrap footerButtons in function, and when I change state and return empty array instead of with buttons, the buttons still remains visible.